# Ripple rings are in backside of map not infront

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, charts, three.js

I'm trying to work with Globe but Ripple rings always going on the backside of the map, not in front of it

I'm using https://github.com/vasturiano/globe.gl/blob/master/example/random-rings/index.html as source
and already I tried BackSide for ripple rings

Also is there anyway to disable rotate with mouse or disable mouseclick or drag

```
    const N = 2;
    const gData = [...Array(N).keys()].map(() => ({
        lat: 35.6892,
        lng: 51.3890,
        maxR: Math.random() * 20 + 10,
        propagationSpeed: 2,
        repeatPeriod:1000
    }));

    const colorInterpolator = t => `rgba(255,100,50,${Math.sqrt(1-t)})`;
    
    const world = Globe()
        (document.getElementById('globeViz'))
        .ringsData(gData)
        .ringColor(() => colorInterpolator)
        .ringMaxRadius('maxR')
        .ringPropagationSpeed('propagationSpeed')
        .ringRepeatPeriod('repeatPeriod')
        // .backgroundColor('rgba(0,0,0,0)')
        .showGlobe(false)
        .showAtmosphere(false);

    fetch('https://unpkg.com/world-atlas/land-110m.json').then(res => res.json())
    .then(landTopo => {
        world
            .polygonsData(topojson.feature(landTopo, landTopo.objects.land).features)
            .polygonCapMaterial(new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                color: '#282828',
                side: THREE.DoubleSide
            }))
            .polygonSideColor(() => 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
    });

    // Add auto-rotation
    world.controls().autoRotate = true;
    world.controls().autoRotateSpeed = 0.9;
```

Preview : https://i.ibb.co/JyjwPL7/s.png

Comment: `ringAltitude` (default: 0.0015) should be greater than `polygonAltitude` (default: 0.01)

Comment: @Shreshth how do you mean?

Comment: I posted the full code in the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, the default [`ringAltitude`](https://github.com/vasturiano/globe.gl#rings-layer) is `0.0015`, whereas the default [`polygonAltitude`](https://github.com/vasturiano/globe.gl#polygons-layer) is `0.01`. If you set the ringAltitude to be greater than polygonAltitude, the rings will appear over the land shapes. Run the snippet below to see it in action.

```js
const N = 2
const gData = [...Array(N).keys()].map(() => ({
  lat: 35.6892,
  lng: 51.389,
  maxR: Math.random() * 20 + 10,
  propagationSpeed: 2,
  repeatPeriod: 1000,
}))

const colorInterpolator = t => `rgba(255,100,50,${Math.sqrt(1 - t)})`

const world = Globe()(document.getElementById('globeViz'))
  .ringsData(gData)
  .ringColor(() => colorInterpolator)
  .ringMaxRadius('maxR')
  .ringPropagationSpeed('propagationSpeed')
  .ringRepeatPeriod('repeatPeriod')
  .ringAltitude(0.015) // <--- change of interest.

fetch('https://unpkg.com/world-atlas/land-110m.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(landTopo => {
    world
      .polygonsData(topojson.feature(landTopo, landTopo.objects.land).features)
      .polygonCapMaterial(
        new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
          color: '#282828',
          side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        }),
      )
      .polygonSideColor(() => 'rgba(0,0,0,0)')
  })

// Add auto-rotation
world.controls().autoRotate = true
world.controls().autoRotateSpeed = -0.9
```

```html
<div id="globeViz"></div>
<script src="//unpkg.com/globe.gl"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/topojson/3.0.2/topojson.min.js"></script>
```